# Highlight a certain candle in candlestick chart

Tags: r, r-plotly, candlestick-chart

I'm learning how to write code for different kinds of charts in R using plotly library. For example:

```
library(plotly)
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("AAPL",src='yahoo')

# basic example of ohlc charts
df <- data.frame(Date=index(AAPL),coredata(AAPL))
df <- tail(df, 30)

maxi_dif <-  as.integer(which (df$diff == max(df$diff)))
maxi_x <- df[maxi_dif,'Date']
maxi_y <- df[maxi_dif,'diff']

fig <- df %>% plot_ly(x = ~Date, type="candlestick",
                      open = ~AAPL.Open, close = ~AAPL.Close,
                      high = ~AAPL.High, low = ~AAPL.Low)
```

There are different kinds of options of how to add legend,hovertext and etc on the plot. I wonder if it's possible to highlight certain candle in the chart? For example based on what candle is the longest/shortest in the data? I'm not very experienced in how these charts work, I only know the basics, so maybe the question is not applicable.
Example of what I want to achieve is in the attached image
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VknYI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add a new trace with filtered data:

```
fig <- df %>% plot_ly(
  x = ~ Date,
  type = "candlestick",
  open = ~ AAPL.Open,
  close = ~ AAPL.Close,
  high = ~ AAPL.High,
  low = ~ AAPL.Low
) %>%
  add_trace(
    data = df %>% filter(Date == "2022-01-28"),
    x = ~ Date,
    type = "candlestick",
    open = ~ AAPL.Open,
    close = ~ AAPL.Close,
    high = ~ AAPL.High,
    low = ~ AAPL.Low,
    increasing = list(fillcolor = "Blue", line = list(color = "Blue")),
    decreasing = list(fillcolors = "Blue", line = list(color = "Blue")),
    showlegend = FALSE
  )
fig
```

[image]